# How to understand the sum in calculation of $\partial_t \sqrt g$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Assume $g_{ij}$ is Riemannian metric. Under the mean curvature flow, we have
$$
\partial_t g_{ij}= -2H h_{ij}
$$
where $H$ is mean curvature , and $h_{ij}$ is second fundamental form. (Forgive me talking it poorly, since this is not key point.)

Then I  calculate the $\partial_t \sqrt g$ as following
$$
\partial_t \sqrt g= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt g} \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}\partial_t g_{ij}
$$
where $g=\det(g_{ij})$ and $A_{ij}$ is algebraic cofactor of $\det(g_{ij})$. Then
$$
\partial_t \sqrt g= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt g} \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}\partial_t g_{ij}= -\frac{H}{\sqrt g} \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}h_{ij}=-\frac{H}{\sqrt g} \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}h_{ij}g_{ij}g^{ij}=-H^2\sqrt g
$$
But I can  not understand
$$
-\frac{H}{\sqrt g} \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}h_{ij}=-\frac{H}{\sqrt g} \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}h_{ij}g_{ij}g^{ij}=-H^2\sqrt g  \tag{1}
$$
In my view, I have
$$
\sum_j g_{ij}g^{ij}=1
$$
so,  I think the first equation of (1)  is not suitable. Besides, in the second equation, there are four $i$ and $j$, I feel disorder in the sum over $i$ and $j$.

PS: (1) is written by me, I am not sure it is right, but the result is right with the pubulic paper (they omit the process).

Comment: Instead of doing (1), consider writing $A_{ij} = \det(g_{ij}) g^{ij}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In writing Einstein notation, you know you screw up while you see the same lower indice. In your expression,

$$\sum_{i,j} A_{ij}h_{ij}g_{ij}g^{ij}, $$

you might probably have this in mind:

$$\sum_{i,j, k,l} A_{ij}h_{ij}g_{kl}g^{kl}.$$

So in particular you do not have

$$A_{ij}h_{ij}g_{ij}g^{ij} = (g^{ij} h_{ij}) (A_{ij} g_{ij}). $$

Instead, just use $g^{ij} = \det (g_{ij}) A_{ij}$ as suggested in the comment. Then

$$\sum_{i,j} A_{ij}h_{ij} = g \sum_{i,j} g^{ij}h_{ij} = gH. $$